# Can't decrypt Ruby encrypted string in Scala

Tags: ruby, scala, encryption

I'm using ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor to encrypt a string in Ruby as follows:

```
salt = SecureRandom.random_bytes(64)
// => "s\x90L\xB8\xEF\x8BBp\xB6\xF5A\x95\xA8]+\x94\xF3\xA7\x9A\x84+jC\xBF\xB0\x15\xEF*\x8C\xDD.\xE5\xC7Y\xCE\xE1\xAA\xA4I/%.\x9E\x14\xC1\xA8\x9E\x122\xE0\x19.\x19\xD8\xB6\xE8\x83\xE1\xFE\x16\xB5\x11N\x18"

key = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new('password').generate_key(salt)
// => "\x12\xBD1\xA0Q\xBF)\\\x89\xDF\x95\xD0\f\x03\x17P'\x87\xAD\x92b\xB5%\xC7X\x01\x9Ar\xCB\xC9\x1A\x10'\xC4\x95w\xBF\xED]\x17\xEB\x9F#\xC6\xEE8S\xE1^\x18\xE2^\x85Z\rJ\x9A\xEE\xA5\xEC|\xA2\xA9\x8E"

crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(key)
encrypted_username = crypt.encrypt_and_sign("daniel")
// => "N0dHcFM3MnQrcW1HUk9UTGwxeUJsZmlCNzcwUGhrdUdtbE9YWnUxamZFST0tLUVUcUlIU2k1ZHIvTmlDRUgzM2FsS0E9PQ==--1ede80eb2b498ddf5133f8f3a45a82db2476c740"
```

Then in Scala I'm trying to decrypt like so:

```
var encrypted_str = "N0dHcFM3MnQrcW1HUk9UTGwxeUJsZmlCNzcwUGhrdUdtbE9YWnUxamZFST0tLUVUcUlIU2k1ZHIvTmlDRUgzM2FsS0E9PQ==--1ede80eb2b498ddf5133f8f3a45a82db2476c740"

val parts = encrypted_str.split("--");

val encryptedData = Base64.decodeBase64(parts(0))

val iv = Base64.decodeBase64(parts(1))

val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv.take(16)));

val result = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
println(new String(result, "UTF-8"))
```

But I run into this error:

javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Comment: Try to encryp it with Scala and see will you get the same result. xD

Comment: That won't work I think....ruby uses a random iv which is appended to the encrypted string

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be here:

```
val iv = Base64.decodeBase64(parts(1))
```

The second part of your message is `1ede80eb2b498ddf5133f8f3a45a82db2476c740` which is not a base 64 encoded string, it's a hex encoded string. Try this instead:

```
Hex.decodeHex(parts(1))
```